# How to build an Ipad web app like GMAIL for the iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, webkit, jqtouch

I'm interested in building am iPad web app like The GMAIL iPad web app. What is the best way to build it? What is the best framework? Jqtouch, webkit, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Why the negative votes. I have no idea where to start?

Comment: perhaps because the question is pretty unanswerable - most people don't use a framework specifically for mobile development, they write it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here is a list of 18 other mobile frameworks with varying levels of complexity and usefulness. (I couldn't use 2 links in a single post)

http://iphoneized.com/2009/11/18-mobile-frameworks-development-tools-creating-iphone-apps/

Answer (score 2):

jQTouch is a stable open source framework developed/designed by some of the same guys that are now working on Sencha Touch, and it has a fairly robust community and extensibility support.

http://jqtouch.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JQuery as your JS development library then [JQuery Mobile](http://www.jquerymobile.com) is the most "Official" mobile framework for it and is currently in the make, as of writing this a Beta release is being cooked, I would certainly go for it since JQuery's people are behind it for continuous development and support.

Answer (score 2):

Well if its just a web app you can create a page with frames.  The're not adjustable but other then that they've been working the same for me.  I have a website that is basically frames and it looks the same on the iPad as in a browser.  The gmail could be a two frame app.
For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sheduler</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="40,*"
    marginheight="0" 
    frameborder="5" framespacing="5">
   <frame name="top" scrolling="no" noresize target="contents" src="/cgi-bin/cgi/ngfop/other2.pl?htmlname=top2.htm&name=Students.xml">
  <frameset cols="30%,*,*">
    <frame name="left" target="main" src="/cgi-bin/cgi/ngfop/other2.pl?htmlname=left01frame.htm&name=blank.xml">
    <frame name="middle" src="/cgi-bin/cgi/ngfop/other2.pl?htmlname=blank.htm">
    <frame name="right"  src="/cgi-bin/cgi/ngfop/other2.pl?htmlname=editschframe.htm&name=blank.xml">
  </frameset>
  <noframes>
  <body>
  <p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p>
  </body>
  </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many frameworks now a days.

I personally used [jquerymobile](http://www.jquerymobile.com) & it looks very promising. I recommend using jquerymobile over others for now as they are releasing new & interesting features on regular bases.